# IDFA error with new Flurry but not old. Why / how to work around?

Tags: ios, flurry, idfa

I have an iOS app that does not display any ads, but I do use Flurry for anonymous data logging.

When I link with Flurry library version 4.2.4, Apple accepts the app with no problems. If I replace this with version 5.2.0, then Apple bounces the submission with the error:

> Improper Advertising Identifier [IDFA] Usage - Your app contains the Advertising Identifier [IDFA] API but you have not indicated its usage on the Prepare for Upload page in iTunes Connect.

Any idea what might be going on here and how I can eventually update to a more recent Flurry library? I don't need the newer functionality right now, but eventually this will bite.

I did try saying "Yes" to the IDFA submission question, but then I have the quandary described here: [IDFA & Google Conversion Tracking SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251385/idfa-google-conversion-tracking-sdk).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store polices. (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)